# Passing parameter over jQuery GET call receive null on server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to make a `GET` call in jQuery passing a parameter here is what I'm doing

```
function getChirurghi() {
    var id = "1";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/ControllerName/GetDataHere",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

On server side the controller is called but the data I'm getting is always null...

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TypeOfObject> GetDataHere([FromBody]string id)
{}
```

Any idea how's that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the value a key so that the ModelBinder can recognise and work with it:

```
data: { id: id },
```

You also need to remove the `[FromBody]` attribute in the action signature, as `GET` data is sent in the URL (either as part of the querystring, or in a routing structure).

Lastly, the options object of `$.ajax()` has no `failure` property so that can be removed as it's redundant.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Another short question. Any way to put more get methods with different names in the same controller?

Comment: Sure, just change the method name. And no problem, glad to help.

Comment: hey @Rory McCrossan sorry to bother again. I tried to add a different `get method` in the same controller but I got the following error: `Multiple actions were found that match the request:
GetDataHere on type WebApplication.Controllers.ControllerName
GetMoreDataHere on type WebApplication.Controllers.ControllerName

ExceptionType:System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: ok. I answer my self. I had to add the `{action}` to the routetemplate `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted @RoryMcrossan, but there is another solution.

you could just add it to the end of the `url`.

```
function getChirurghi() {
var id = "1";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/ControllerName/GetDataHere/" + id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }
});
```